# How to : I would like to have several rectangles (box?) autoresized to browser's height

Tags: html, css, muse

Alright, so I know my question is probably not clear, but I do have a very simple example that I can direct you to in order to better understand what I am asking. 
Check out this website http://www.spelltower.com
It's a simple one page layout with anchors. I like the fact that when you go to a section, the coloured rectangle is always adjusting to your browser's height, even if you change it while on the site. Basically, each rectangle (representing a section on the site) always fills the browser's window, even if you resize it.

I would like to do something similar on my website. Any help would be appreciated.
I hope this can be accomplished with simple html code. I am using Adobe Muse to do most of my site.

Answer (score 1):

For the width you can use width=100% option in css. But for the height you have to use javascript to get the viewport height and assign it to the divs. You can use $(window).height() to get the height of your browser.

Comment: Ok, so basically, I would have to have javascript constantly checking on the browsers height and use that variable as my "new" height for the boxes I use? If so, does that mean that the script has to be running all the time or does resizing the browser automatically triggers those things? Sorry, kinda of a new "web designer" here (not that I am a Web Designer, but mostly an enthusiast user).

Comment: No, that function only runs when page loads. you can check for browser resize with onresize function and get the height value again.

Answer (score 1):

you can always use the style="height:1vh;" ( ViewportHieght ) css yo do that.